# Measure/dimension line (line parallel to a line)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a problem drawing a slanted "measure line" parallel to a line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (1,1);
\coordinate (B) at (4,4);
\fill (A) circle(.5mm);
\fill (B) circle(.5mm);
\draw (A)--(B);
\coordinate (P1) at ($($(A)!1!(B)$)!.2cm!90:(B)$);
\coordinate (P2) at ($($(A)!0!(B)$)!.2cm!90:(B)$);
\draw[|<->|] (P1)--(P2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Notice that the line ends incorrectly using "1" and changing 1 to "0.9999" in (A)!1!(B) makes it better. I guess there is a better way to do this. TIA.

Comment: ` ($(A)!1!(B)$)` is really just `(B)`, try `\draw ($(A)!1!(B)$) circle[radius=2mm];`. So the line segment is too short. But there is no need to use any of these constructions, just using `(A)` and `(B)` with angles `90` and `-90` is sufficient.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just use `(A)` and `(B)`. Then the segment is long enough to get a good result.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (1,1);
\coordinate (B) at (4,4);
\fill (A) circle(.5mm);
\fill (B) circle(.5mm);
\draw (A)--(B);
\coordinate (P1) at ($(A)!.2cm!90:(B)$);
\coordinate (P2) at ($(B)!.2cm!-90:(A)$);
\draw[|<->|] (P1)--(P2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a `dimline` like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-dimline, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (1,1);
\coordinate (B) at (4,4);
\fill (A) circle(.5mm);
\fill (B) circle(.5mm);
\draw (A)--(B);
\dimline[extension start length=0.4 cm, extension end length=0.4 cm] {($(A)!.4cm!90:(B)$)} {($(B)!.4cm!-90:(A)$)}{10};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: line with dimline]

Or without a label:

```
\dimline[extension start length=0.4 cm, extension end length=0.4 cm, label style=transparent] {($(A)!.4cm!90:(B)$)} {($(B)!.4cm!-90:(A)$)}{};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the - in my opinion - amazing package [`tkz-euclide`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide) and do something like:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm, tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoints{
        1/1/A,
        4/4/B}
        \tkzDrawSegment[dim={,4mm,transparent}](A,B)
        \tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use the `[turn]` option.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(0,0) coordinate (A) node[below]{$A$} 
(4,3) coordinate (B) node[right]{$B$}
(A)--(B)--([turn]90:2mm)  coordinate (Bt)
(B)--(A)--([turn]-90:2mm) coordinate (At);
\draw[red] (A)--(B);
\draw[|<->|,gray,very thin] (At)--(Bt) node[midway,above,sloped,scale=.8,black]{$5$ cm};
\fill (A) circle(1pt) (B) circle(1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Different forms of parallels and perpendicular:

```
% parallel4.tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \coordinate (a) at (0,1);
    \coordinate (b) at (3,2);
    \coordinate (c) at (2.5,0);

    \node[left] at (a){a};
    \node[right] at (b){b};
    \node[below] at (c){c};

    \draw[gray!40] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;

    % Project the middle point (p): (.)(p)(.) over line (.)(.)
    \draw[red]    (a) -- ($(b)!(a)!(c)$);
    \draw[green]  (b) -- ($(a)!(b)!(c)$);
    \draw[blue]   (c) -- ($(a)!(c)!(b)$);

    \draw[->] ($(a)!(3,1)!(b)$) -- (3,1) ;


    % Perpendicular at a position in the middle of a line (.)(.)
    % and with a length d:   (.)x(.)d
    % first number is the position, second, the length but
    % taking a proportion of the first position 
    \draw[->] ($(a)!.5!(c)!.1!90:(a)$) -- ($(a)!.5!(c)!.1!-90:(a)$) ;

    % Parallel to (.)(.) at a distance d: (.)d(.)
    \draw[->] ($(a)!-.1!90:(c)$) -- ($(c)!-.1!-90:(a)$) ;

    \coordinate (A) at (0,3);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,5);
    \fill (A) circle(.5mm) node[below] {A};
    \fill (B) circle(.5mm) node[right] {B};
    \draw (A)--(B);

    % Parallel to (.)(.) to measure:
    \coordinate (P1) at ($(A)!.2cm!90:(B)$);
    \coordinate (P2) at ($(B)!.2cm!-90:(A)$);
    \draw[|<->|] (P1)--(P2);

    % directamente
    \draw[|>-<|] ($(A)!-.2cm!90:(B)$)--($(B)!-.2cm!-90:(A)$);

    % Parallel to measure but with lines limiting:
    \draw[shorten >= -0.25cm] (a) -- ($(a)!0.1!90:(b)$);
    \draw[shorten >= -0.25cm] (b) --($(b)!0.1!-90:(a)$);
    \draw[<->] ($(a)!0.1!90:(b)$)--($(b)!0.1!-90:(a)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]