# Unstable measurement macro

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have created a macro `\measurement` which allows me to add measurements to my drawings. It works well, but the labels are sometimes volatile. In the example below, the measurement labels are rotated differently even though the commands are virtually identical. I assume there must be a better way to control the labelling. Does anyone have an idea?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{myscale/.code={\edef\myscale{#1}\tikzset{scale=#1}}}
\def\myscale{1}

\newcommand{\measure}[4]{%
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\mylength{8pt/\myscale}
\draw[very thin] #1 -- ($#1!\mylength!-90:#2$) coordinate (a) -- ($#1!\mylength+0.4*\mylength!-90:#2$);
\draw[very thin] #2 -- ($#2!\mylength!90:#1$) coordinate (b) -- ($#2!\mylength+0.4*\mylength!90:#1$);
\draw[very thin,<->,>=stealth] (a) -- (b) node[auto,sloped,#3] {#4};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[myscale=0.12]
\begin{scope}[rotate=20]

\draw[red] (0,0) -- (0,12);
\measure{(0,0)}{(0,12)}{midway,above,rotate=20,font=\small}{red}

\draw[blue] (0,12) -- (0,24);
\measure{(0,12)}{(0,24)}{midway,above,rotate=20,font=\small}{blue}

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use a `dimline` for this. Search "dimline" or see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/575964/8650

Comment: Interesting effect, it almost only appears with this `scale` and `rotate` values.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes, I am aware that this happens only for certain combinations of scale and rotation.  But as I am using this macro for years, I regularly stumble on such combinations, which is extremely annoying.  I wonder if there is a better solution to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a vertical(except for rounding) line, that you then rotate 20 deg. Depending on the rounding, the line is leaning a little to the left or a little to the right and the node is naturally flipped.

I have not tried to investigate, what you try to do or how best to do it - maybe an other question.

So the answer is: *Vertical makes it unstable*.

To see the effect, try this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
nodetest/.pic={
\coordinate (c) at (1,10); %intermediate coordinate to create rounding
\draw (1,0) -- (c) node[auto, sloped, midway] {test};
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \pos in {0.01,0.02,...,2} 
\pic[scale=\pos] at (10*\pos,0) {nodetest};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Scaled lines from (0,0) to (1,10):

[image: Triangle of lines with band of nodes]

Scaled lines from (2,0) to (1,10):

[image: Triangle of lines with band of nodes]

Scaled lines from (1,0) to (1,10):

[image: Triangle of lines with unstable band of nodes]

It is seen that the dark band of nodes in the middle is unstable for vertical lines.

Edit:

I can only guess what you want. The following shows nodes parallel and below the line read from the first coordinate to the second. It is stable on all scales.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \ang in {0,20,...,340}{
\coordinate (a) at (\ang:1);
\coordinate (b) at (\ang:4);
\draw[Stealth-Stealth] (a) --node[sloped, auto, swap, allow upside down=true]{red} (b);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Circle of double arrows with labels]

Comment: +1 Thanks, that was helpful and my hunch for the problem was along those lines as well. But the OP already asks for the solution, so I don't think it's a good idea to open a new question.

Comment: What is "above" and "below" a vetical line? I do not suggest that you ask the same question again, but a question where you explain the need for a scale in the first place?, an usual scale much below one?, a scope to rotate draws?, but not nodes that then are rotated some places? Should your solution detect the rotation angle and then place the node correctly? Defining "myscale"? There are so many things that I do not understand. You probably have good reason for it all, but I can not help with a solution to a problem I do not understand.

Comment: I use `myscale` because this way I can manually scale other picture elements that would otherwise not scale. I draw a real picture and scale it later to fit the available space, so the scaling can vary greatly from picture to picture. But basically, I'd be happy if there was an alternative to the `sloped` command that did not rotate the node depending on the line direction. Yes, I would have to do this manually, but then at least the situation would be predictable. I can enter this information in OP.

Comment: Yes, the fact that `allow upside down=true` prevents automatic rotating and makes the result predictable is good enough for me. I will rotate labels manually if I need to, I just need to be stable when I change rotation angle or scaling a bit.  I will still leave the question open for a while, while I am testing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps - with `tkz-euclide`

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
    

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,-4/4/B}
    \tkzDefPointWith[linear,K=0.5](A,B)
    \tkzGetPoint{C}

    \tkzDrawSegment[red, very thick](A,C)
    \tkzDrawSegment[blue,very thick](B,C)
    \tkzDrawPoints[color=black](A,B,C)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above right=3pt](A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawSegment[style=red, dashed, dim={$10$,15pt,midway,font=\scriptsize, rotate=45}](A,C) 
    \tkzDrawSegment[style=blue, dashed, dim={$10$,15pt,midway,font=\scriptsize, rotate=45}](C,B) 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```